# Android WorkManager - Run task when phone is fully charged

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I have a project in which I want to run a task in WorkManager when battery is fully charged. I almost searched everywhere but I couldn't find any solution.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    //I want to run this task when battery is full.

    if(BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING==100) {
          showNotification();
    }

    return Result.success();
}
```

and the code snippet which starts the WorkManager:

```
private void startWorkManager() {


    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
        .setRequiresCharging(true)
        .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest= new
            PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWork.class 
    ,15,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
}
```

update the contractor

public NotificationWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.context = context;

```
}

public double batteryLevel(Context context){

    Intent batteryIntent = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    double scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    double level = -1;
    if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
        level = rawlevel / scale;
    }
    return level;    //This will return the value in range of 0.0-1.0
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    if (batteryLevel(context) == 1.0) {  //1.0 means 100%

      showNotification();

        return Result.success();
    } else {
          return Result.retry();
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32608760/8043806) using `broadcast reciever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, In your worker class, create a `batteryLevel(Context context)` function to get battery level.

```
public double batteryLevel(Context context){

    Intent batteryIntent = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
                new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    double scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    double level = -1;
    if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
        level = rawlevel / scale;
    }
    return level;    //This will return the value in range of 0.0-1.0
}
```

Then in your `doWork()` method, check for battery level, if it's 100%:

```
if (batteryLevel(context) == 1.0){  //1.0 means 100%
    //Do your stuff
    return Result.success()
}else{
    return Result.retry()
}
```

**Update**
Create a class level context object.

```
Context context;
```

Initialize your constructor with following parameters

```
public NotificationWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams){
    super(context,workParams);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198908/discussion-on-answer-by-mysterious-guy-android-workmanager-run-task-when-phone).